# Implementing hierarchical structure in sqlite

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I'm a beginner with SQL, I'm writing a C# app using SQLite. I need help with implementing hierarchical structure shown in here https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPf6C.jpg in my database. I know that with Private accounts it would be table called PrivateAccounts (should've called it PersonalAccounts not private, but it doesn't matter that much right now) and there I would throw many rows with IDs, Logins etc. However how to do it with Company accounts, where there's general account for a company and to this account I need to link accounts of people working for that company? Would it be efficient to create table for every company? It would make a big mess in database though, since I would like to have one database for both company accounts and personal accounts if possible

Comment: You'll want to learn about *one to many* relationships and how that is portrayed in a DB.  As posted this is far too broad for SO

Comment: You also need to study [database normalization](https://www.bing.com/search?q=normalization+tutorial&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=normalization+tutorial&sc=1-22).

Comment: It would **not** be efficient (nor effective) to create a table for every account,  It would not be advised that you necessarily have seperate tables for personal, business, private or whatever else accounts.  What type account it is can be portrayed by a type qualifier on the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest 3 tables.

An **Entity** table that holds details of account owners (and to cater for sub-compnaies using a reference to an owning entity) and has a column for the type (Private or Company).

An **Account** table that has the name and owner of the account.

An **Account Transaction** table for recording the transactions, basically two columns one reference the account (and therefore the entity) and the amount of the transaction.

The above is pretty simplistic and you'd likely want to add more columns.

## Example

The following is a brief demonstration that culminates in the account balances with the account name, direct owners name and the type of the account displayed.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS entity;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS account;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS account_transaction;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entity (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, entity_name TEXT, entity_type INTEGER, entity_owning_entity);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, account_name TEXT, entity_reference INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account_transaction (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, account_reference INTEGER, amount REAL);
INSERT INTO entity (entity_name, entity_type, entity_owning_entity)
    VALUES
        ("Company 1",1,null), -- will be id 1 
        ("Company 2",1, null), -- will be id 2
      ("Sub Company A",1,1), -- Owned by Company 1 will be id 3
        ("Sub Company B",1,1), -- Owned by Company 1 will be id 4
        ("Sub Company X",1,2), -- Owned by Company 2 will be id 5
        ("Sub Company Y",1,2), -- Owned by Company 2 will be id 6
        ("Fred",0,null), -- Not owned personal type (0) will be id 7
        ("Mary",0,null) -- Not owned, personal type, will be id 8
;
INSERT INTO account (account_name, entity_reference)
    VALUES
        ("Fred's Cheque",7), -- id 1
        ("Sub A Cheque",3), -- id 2
        ("Fred's Savings",7), -- id 3
        ("Mary's Cheque",8), -- id 4
      ("Sub X Chequ",5) -- id 5
;

INSERT INTO account_transaction (account_reference, amount)
    VALUES
        (3,123.45),(3,57.55),(3,200), -- 381 for Fred's Cheque (i.e. references id 3 in the account table)
        (2,100),(2,100),(2,100),(2,100), -- 400 for Sub A Cheque (i.e. references id 2)
        (1,10),
        (4,15),(4,15),(4,30),
        (5,13),(5,14),(5,15),(5,16),(5,17)
;

WITH cte1(id,name) AS 
  -- Use Common Table Expression (temp table) to resolve owner of an entity
    (SELECT id, (SELECT entity_name FROM entity WHERE me.entity_owning_entity = id) FROM entity AS me)

-- Main SELECT Query
SELECT
  -- Handle case when no entity owner or when entity owner
  CASE
        WHEN (SELECT name FROM cte1 where cte1.id = entity.id) IS NULL 
            THEN entity_name
            ELSE (SELECT name FROM cte1 where cte1.id = entity.id)||'-'||entity_name
    END AS AccountOwner,
    account_name AS Account, -- Show the axccount_name
    sum(amount) AS Balance,  -- Show the balance
    -- Use and appropriate value for the type (private or company account)
    CASE
            WHEN entity_type = 1 THEN 'Company'
            WHEN entity_type = 0 THEN 'Private'
        END AS Type
FROM account_transaction -- main table
    JOIN account ON account.id = account_reference -- relationship to the account table
    JOIN entity ON entity.id = entity_reference -- relationship to the entity table
GROUP BY account.id -- group according to accounts (i.e. 1 row is made from all rows in a group for aggregates such a sum)
ORDER BY AccountOwner -- Order result according to the Account Owner 
;
```

## Result

The SELECT query will return :-

[image]

- Note you wouldn't typically make assumptions about id's being specific values, the assumption that they are has been used for the sake of brevity.